# How can I track the first time a record is viewed?

Tags: history-tracking, trigger

How can I track this?

Trying this - On change of LastViewDate
Looks like I cannot hook into this using Apex/PB/Flow - When LastViewDate is not null. New records have no LastViewedDate, so the theory is to hook into changes on this field.

Comment: if the class version is 28.0+ then this field should be accessible via Apex.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I just found

http://www.cloudsuccess.com/blog/setting-up-last-viewed-by-in-salesforce/

Shame I cannot do without Apex

Comment: Well, you can't do this without apex.